# Play audio from non-imported src

Tags: reactjs, audio

I want to play an audio with reactjs and the src comes from a database and change the src dynamicaly.
So fare I can play an audio that I import but if I don’t import it I get the error:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:3000/audio-lib/soundTest.mp3 failed.
```

How can I replace this: **state = { audioSrc: soundTest};** By something like this: **state = { audioSrc: "../audio-lib/soundTest.mp3"};**

This code works but I want to remove the import:

```
// I don't want this import
import soundTest from "../audio-lib/soundTest.mp3"
...
 state = { audioSrc: soundTest};
...
  render () {
        return(
            <audio
                controls
                ref={ ref => this.player = ref} >
                <source src={this.state.audioSrc} type="audio/mp3"/>
            </audio>        
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I used the react-sound package. 
With this component it's easy to load a sound from a url passed as props.
npm doc:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sound